# PHP ignoring returned reference from function considered harmful?

Tags: php, memory-leaks, reference, php-internals

Derick Rethans has [an old article](http://derickrethans.nl/talks/phparch-php-variables-article.pdf) that says:

> Please do note that it is harmful not to accept a reference from a
>   function that returns a reference. In some cases, PHP will get
>   confused and cause memory corruptions which are very hard to find and
>   debug. It is also not a good idea to return a static value as
>   reference, as the PHP engine has problems with that too. In PHP 4.3,
>   both cases can lead to very hard to reproduce bugs and crashes of PHP
>   and the web server. **In PHP 5, this works all a little bit better. Here
>   you can expect a warning and it will behave “properly”.**

Does it mean that in PHP 5 we are allowed to ignore the returned reference from a function?

By that, I mean this:

```
function &GetRef(&$array){
    $item =& $array[0];
    return $item;
}

$array = array(0, 1, 2);
$item =& GetRef($array); /* Normal usage of the function using assign by reference
                            also known as "accepting" the reference. */

$item = GetRef($array); /* Notice that here we didn't assign by reference.
                           Are we allowed to ignore the returned reference
                           and simply do normal assignment? */
```

The [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php#language.references.return) states:

> Unlike parameter passing, here [return by reference] you have to use &
>   in both places - to indicate that you want to return by reference, not
>   a copy, and to indicate that reference binding, rather than usual
>   assignment, should be done for $myValue.

It doesn't explicitly say that we *must* accept the returned reference.

Does it mean that we are free to ignore returned references?

Comment: Maybe you should ask Derick Ethans... he's the only one who actually knows exactly what he meant by "a little bit better"

Comment: @FDL, That's not the point... are things fixed in PHP 5 and we don't get engine crashes or are things not fully fixed and we should avoid ignoring returned references?

Comment: Given that PHP 4.3 is over 10 years old, and the engine has been completely rewritten since then, I don't think you need have any nightmares about this

Comment: I think if we are saying about bug, there could be only two states: it is fixed or it persists. **A little bit better** means that bug still persists - I think, there could be no other meanings. So you should be aware of that and avoid situations that leads to appearing of that bug.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo, so basically your opinion is different from Mark?

Comment: Not entirely differs. If I can not be sure in something - I will certainly avoid situations with something undefined. So, if there is no direct confirmations of that bug been fixed, I will avoid such cases. I agree with @MarkBaker that engine could be rewritten, but there's no guarantee that the bug was fixed.

Comment: You know, there's an easy way to get a practical answer to this question.  Write some code that returns a reference, call it like a billion times, and see how much memory is used.  If it finishes and isn't using over like half a GB, you're fine.

Comment: @cHao that is not en easy way, and, due to unstable of that bug, there is a probability that in your certain environment and your tries it will not appear.

Comment: To look at the question another way, without any definitive confirmation that no problem still exists, why not just avoid these situations in case there still is an issue.

Comment: There can be no guarantees that any piece of software is completely bug free: that includes PHP itself. In fact, with every release, there is a changleog that details all bugs that have been fixed as well as listing the new features.

Comment: However, if a known bug has persisted in PHP for over 10 years and through a complete rewrite of the underlying engine, then either it's something that occurs so infrequently in reality that you don't need to worry about it, or the Ruby/Python/Java brigade would have been using it as ammunition to prove how superior those languages are, and the whole world would be aware of it. Me? I'll worry about it if I ever encounter it, and I'll accept my return by reference values where appropriate, but otherwise I'm not going to lose any sleep over it

Comment: @Anigel: Because it doesn't do any good to accept a reference you're not going to use.  Worse than that, it causes some magic reference stuff that can make it hard to pin down where your variables' values are getting changed.

Comment: @MarkBaker, I mean that's not the point. Point is are we *supposed* to accept returned references or are we allowed to ignore it? I'm querying the interface.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo: BS.  PHP doesn't just toss values around at random and hope for the best.  The behavior is deterministic, and is entirely based on PHP itself and the behavior of the program.

Comment: `In PHP 5, this works all a little bit better. Here you can expect a warning and it will behave “properly”.` While the language is a bit woolly and vague, this suggests that it is not an issue in PHP5. Because PHP is Open Source, I could wade through it all checking for myself that it is truly fixed, and that returned references will be discarded if my code doesn't accept them; but as Derick suggests that the problem is fixed in PHP 5, I'm inclined to believe him until I encounter anything to suggest otherwise

Comment: @cHao, the question is regarding the API. Are we *allowed* to do something like this? Because if not, we can't guarantee a future version will work even if it works now....

Comment: @Pacerier: You were *allowed* to do something like this all along.  It just didn't work out too well for the author before PHP 5.  I personally never had a problem with it, and frankly, i find the paragraph uselessly vague anyway.  Guy was showing diagrams and explaining references like a pro, and then comes up with some "oh, there can be a bug here" with no further info?  I'd consider the whole paragraph void unless he can come up off an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you should generally ignore *at least that section* in the linked article, if not the entire thing.

The article talks about references in the context of PHP 4.3, released in *December, 2002* and EOL'd at the end of 2007.  PHP 4 should never be used today.  As a general rule, when it comes to learning about working with PHP, you should *not* trust any article that targets PHP versions older than 5.2 (as of mid-2013).

PHP 5.0 features Zend Engine 2, a new virtual machine on which PHP runs.  This is where references are implemented.  5.1 introduces [some backwards-incompatible changes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration51.references.php) with regard to manipulation of return values.  5.3 introduces [real garbage collection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php) and [deprecates both call-time pass-by-reference and assigning `new` by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php).  These important changes are not addressed by that prehistoric article.

> Does it mean that in PHP 5 we are allowed to ignore the returned reference from a function?

Yes.  Modern PHP versions have no problem with discarding the return value of *any* function, reference or not.  If you encounter behavior that seems to contradict this expectation, create a reduced test case and file a bug with the PHP maintainers.

Also, think twice before using references in your code.  Passing around references will not save time, will not save memory and will not increase performance except in rare cases.  Use them sparingly to keep complexity under control.

Comment: That article is good because it goes in-depth. Pity it's for PHP 4. As for PHP 5, do you recommend any material that goes in-depth on references? The stuff in the PHP manual is simply insufficient.